# YA Time travel/teleportation novel. Plot required using helmet (or other head gear)

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

YA Time travel/teleportation novel. Plot required using helmet (or other head gear)... but only for training. A young kid (less than sixteen?) finds he can either teleport or time travel (**I don't exactly remember which one**). He is given a helmet, and told that if he wears it, he will be able to travel wherever he thinks.

Later in the story, he is told he can actually do it whenever he wants, without requiring the helmet. The helmet was purely for training his mind.

The "gift" would eventually disappear as the person got older.

I remember reading this novel in my school library around eight years ago...

Comment: The part about an item being needed at first, then revealed to be merely a prop, reminds me of a Diana Wynne Jones story, but I can't remember which one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the book you're looking for (assuming you didn't already find it) is Time Twister by Ged Maybury?

I found this question while trying to find out the title to this one myself. It's time travel and not teleport though (although possibly the time travel involved teleporting too?).

[This blog post](http://farah-sf.blogspot.ca/2005/05/new-zealand-future-ged-maybury-time.html) includes a bit of a synopsis.

The general gist of the story is that there's a video game in the arcade named Time Twister, part of which involves a helmet that you wear. Once a brother and sister get good at it they get whisked into the future to meet with someone named YOS, who recruits them to try and stop a computer corporation from taking over the world, saving their dad in the process.

The blog post linked above doesn't mention it and I don't recall exactly (it's been a long, long while since I read it) but it seems familiar that the helmet was not really needed.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: Done and done, sir!

Comment: Excellent addition - well done again!