# A book about a time travel standup arcade game

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult

The book was definitely written before the late 90s, when I read it, but it's about a standup arcade so I'm guessing probably originally published in the 80s.

Two kids, I think a brother and sister, find an arcade game that lets them time travel. They are led into using it by a mysterious figure named "Yos"; I think they're fighting an evil corporation but I'm not sure. At the end, they discuss their adventure and realize that Yos was a different gender for each of them, then realize that it's actually an acronym for "Your Older Self" and it was them time travelling back to help them as kids.

The cover looked very DDR-ish, with a vector-graphics road of coloured squares receding in one-point persepctive (in the book, that's how the arcade game is described as looking). I *think* the title was the name of the arcade game itself, but am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is  [*Time Twister*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6965093-time-twister) by Ged Maybury.

Per [TV Tropes](https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/My_Future_Self_and_Me);

> The protagonist travels into the future and meets a man who introduces himself as "Yos", and tells the protagonist what he needs to do in the present to avert an imminent catastrophe. Near the end of the book, he learns that his sister has also travelled into the future and met Yos -- but the Yos she met was a woman. **They realise that "Yos" is an acronym: Your older self.**

Comment: And assuming this is the correct answer, this question is a dupe of [YA Time travel/teleportation novel. Plot required using helmet (or other head gear)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83471/ya-time-travel-teleportation-novel-plot-required-using-helmet-or-other-head-ge)

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. Although the points that questioner remembered don't overlap with the ones I remembered at all.

Comment: @Zyzzyva - [Great stuff.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)